# pdfpages adds the page *before* the section title, despite being declared after

Tags: floats, pdf, pdfpages

I'd like to add a "supporting information" section and include all of my NMR PDFs. This is what my LaTeX looks like:

```tex
\clearpage
\section{Supporting Information}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/Ethylvanillin.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/Hydrogen Diantilis.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/Methyl Diantilis.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/Ethyl Diantilis.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/n-Propyl Diantilis.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/Isopropyl Diantilis.pdf}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: PDF]

The section title is on the wrong page!

Comment: Try with `\section{<title>} \leavevmode \includepdf[..]{...}`.

Comment: @Werner Just defualt everything

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: No dice on the \leavevmode, the section title still comes after the first PDF. `\documentclass[journal=joceah,manuscript=article,layout=twocolumn]{achemso}`

Comment: Switching to one-column mode using `\onecolumn` adds the title above the first PDF -- but on a completely separate page, which is less than ideal.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. Can you provide a minimal document that replicates the behaviour? Something that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, uses standard images available to everyone (like `example-image`, `example-image-a`, ...) that allows us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: Thanks! I've actually managed to find a solution but it isn't pretty. I've posted the answer in case you want to see it.

Comment: It's really possible to help further unless we can replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out a solution that does what I want like this:

```tex
\documentclass[journal=joceah,manuscript=article,layout=twocolumn]{achemso}

% ...

\clearpage
\onecolumn
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\section{Supporting Information}}]{../NMR/Out/Ethylvanillin.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-]{../NMR/Out/Ethylvanillin.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/Hydrogen Diantilis.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/Methyl Diantilis.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/Ethyl Diantilis.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/n-Propyl Diantilis.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../NMR/Out/Isopropyl Diantilis.pdf}
```

It ain't pretty because:

1. It assumes there *are* at least two pages in `Ethylvanillin.pdf`, which may or may not be true.
2. It requires specifying the ethylvanillin pdf twice
3. It does not separate the layout (section title, one column) from the data (PDFs) effectively, and couples the two too strongly by requiring me to specify the layout (section title) inside the PDF command.

If anybody has a cleaner solution I'd love to see it.